# Sharepoint 2010 developing custom webparts that accepts external file names as properties

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2010 is it feasible to develop a custom webpart that accepts multiple external files like JS, CSS and HTML files, like these files must be specified by end users in the webpart properties window and then the webpart should render the content in all these file on the page.

Any ideas or references?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the Content Editor Web Part already does exactly this? I mean sure it's restricted to rendering web-stuff like HTML, CSS, and JS and you can only pick one file at a time, but just creating a single file containing all of your assets as markup and referencing it in the content editor would accomplish what you want... and not require a bunch of custom development to make work

Comment: I tried this. In a single HTML file I referenced multiple CSS and JS files and in the content editor webpart "Content Link" text box, I gave the relative path of that .html file from the style library. But it gave me error that FORM tags are not supported and it dosnet render the UI any thoughts?

Comment: Form tags aren't supported on SharePoint aspx pages regardless of how you insert them (try adding one with SharePoint Designer and you'll see the same message). They're used internally by the framework, and could result in indeterminate information being posted back to SharePoint page.. you should just use <divs> and other HTML elements to group your form elements -- with regular <button type="button"> style buttons wired up to your own JS handlers to do things like submitting data. You'll also find you can use a text file as the source for a content editor and it will still render properly.

Comment: thanks Eric and Jhon.Once I removed that form tag everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done yes, the content link on a CEWP is an example of this. I don't think it is feasible though. You open the door to exploits and security issues. You wouldn't blindly render unknown user JS, they could have exploits or any other sort of hacks in there. Then there's the permission issues of fetching the files, how would that be handled?

I think here you'd want a web part with customizable properties that you then roll into the display of the web part.